# Connectedness of a cone

Tags: general-topology

> How to prove the set $$A=\Big\{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3: z^2 \geq x^2+y^2, z>0\Big\}$$ is connected in $\Bbb R^3$ ?

Geometrically, $x^2+y^2=z^2$ represents the cone

[image]

So the set $A$ is something like the region bounded by the cone, so it is connected. But how to prove mathematically ? I also search the continuous map from a connected set whose image is $A$, but I can't get. Any help ?

Comment: only the "upper" half of your plot is the cone $A$.

Comment: The set as described is the upper half of the cone, omitting the vertex. It’s convex, and automatically not merely connected, but pathwise connected.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, $A$ is path connected:

if $(x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2)\in A$, then you can show by direct substitution into the defining condition on $A$ that if $t\in [0,1]$, then  $(1-t)(x_1,y_1,z_1)+t(x_2,y_2,z_2)\in A$ and of course, this is a path in $A$ from $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$.